# using php switch code smell or not

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am writing a class and method in PHP that uses switch to call other methods dependant on the specific url.  Example below :

```
switch($this->clean([$_POST['task']))
{
    case "edit":
        $this->editssomething();
    break;
    case "save":
        $this->savesomethingelse();
    break;
    default:
        $this->dodefault();
    break;
}
```

Is this classed as code smell, and should I be refactoring it or could it be classed as a Factory class.

Thank you

Comment: Seems to me that this is exactly what `switch` was meant for.

Comment: it's usually a lot clearer than a load of `if/else if` blocks.

Comment: I've never heard the term "code smell" before, so thank you for bringing to my attention that there is a name for it ^.^

Comment: Thats absolutely fine. The whole concept of the switch statement was to reduce the amount of nested and messy if statements! This is good programming practice! :)

Comment: This will probably get closed as opinion-based, but it's generally good practice to have separate controller methods for each action. So have separate `/save` and `/edit` routes, rather than a dispatcher that handles them based on another request parameter.

Comment: I have read alot about the switch statment being code smell and it would violate the Open-Closed Principle.

Comment: Using a switch is not your problem. You should be thinking about using a more modern approach to routing. Look at the way some of the popular PHP frameworks route requests if you don't understand.

Comment: I saw this back in Mambo cms, so I started using it. BUT ....

Comment: For your particular code, I see the need for a REST type routing. Let the router make the decision as to what Controller / Method action is run.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I have looked at them, but I am new at php I I dont see how I would route a request like php?section=items&id=1&task=edit.

Comment: At least watch some youtube videos or read before you proceed: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

Comment: as far your code remains that simple and i doubt it, there is no need to refactor this. 
But if you want apply more advandced structure, 
 you need definitely an more advanced technique, perhaps an abstract class
https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.  I have now change all my code to keep within refactoring whilst not violating the Open-Closed principle.

Answer (score 2):

That smells good, but default does not need "break", also be sure to name your function with camel or "_"

```
switch( $this->clean($_POST['task']) )
{
    case "edit":
        $this->editssomething();
    break;

    case "save":
        $this->savesomethingelse();
    break;

    default:
        $this->dodefault();
}
```